# I am trying to get speciffic value from a column in sql server but getting error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to get only email value from column which contains all contact details like Username, Phone and Email.

Eg: The coulmn value will look like:

> LastName,  FirstName 
>  phone: 123456789 
>  email: abc@xy.com

I have used the following statement.

```
SUBSTRING(Contact, LEN(LEFT(Contact, CHARINDEX ('email:', Contact))) + 7, LEN(Contact) - 
LEN(RIGHT(Contact, LEN(Contact) - CHARINDEX ('.com', Contact))) - 1)
```

If the column does not have email i am getting the following error

```
Msg 537, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.
```

I am getting the value only if the column has value email but we have some records where column contact does not have email. it will have only UserName.

Please let me know how to get only the email value if it exist in that column contact

Comment: You may need to add logic to cater to that a given column value may not have either `email:` or `phone:`.  If either key be missing, it could be causing the error you are currently seeing.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen for some records we have only Username in that column so in that case it will definitely throw error. i have tried using the below statement but its pulling the user name and phone number if the email doesnot exisit.
SUBSTRING(c.contact,CHARINDEX('email:',c.contact)+7,LEN(c.contact))

Comment: Your table needs to be redefined. Why do you have 1 column that has varying options of content - some with names, some with names and emails etc.

Your table should have separate columns for name, email, phone

Also, what about email addresses that don't have ".com"? With so many top domains there is no way to code for all possible scenarios.